# Multi phase vs single phase power factors

Tags: three-phase, math, power-factor-correction

Are there any differences between calculating single phase and multi phase power factors?  I'm open to general answers, but more specifically:

If PF1=P/S, does PF3=(Pa+Pb+Pc)/(Sa+Sb+Sc)?

Does averaging work: PF3 = (PFa+PFb+PFc)/3?

Could a reactive load in one phase throw off the power factor of the others, or is power factor pretty well isolated between phases?

I thought I knew the answers to these questions from deriving them mathematically, but some meter readings today are making me question myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all apperant powers as complex values then calculate p/s where p is the realpart and s its magnitude.